# Use a docker container as a proxy to use a VPN

Tags: docker

Because of [this problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/895278/not-able-to-access-to-the-internet-in-a-container-on-a-vpn), I'm not able to use the VPN on my host machine and have access to the internet on the containers at the same time. To solve the problem, I want to run a container with access to the VPN and redirect requests from my host to this container.

**Disclaimer : I'm not a network manager and I don't understand completly everything.**

I was able to use the VPN inside a container by using [stono/ike](https://github.com/Stono/ike). My idea was to use socat to redirect requests. Here is the command is use :

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged -v ~/.ike/sites:/sites --userns host stono/ike typ username password # run the container
docker inspect <container-id> | grep IPAddress # To get the IP address of the container
sudo socat UDP-LISTEN:500,fork,reuseaddr UDP:172.17.0.2:500 # redirects the port 500
sudo socat UDP-LISTEN:4500,fork,reuseaddr UDP:172.17.0.2:4500 # redirects the port 4500
```

All commands succed but I still not able to have access to the VPN with my host machine.

So, what can I do? Am I on the good way and what's the solution?